# a scenario to be implemented using awk utility

Tags: python, linux, awk

I have a file (very big in size) which contains lines and each line has some fields in it which are separated by comma.

From this file, I have to extract few fields and dump them into a new line. But the complication here is that, one last field(column) itself contains a comma but that particular field is identified by double quotes "some,thing" (lets say).

Let me give an example:-

```
the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, right, over, the little, "lazy,dog"
```

There are many such lines in this file which is comma separated.

There could be many commas within that last column,

Now I need to extract few columns out of it, for which last one is surely i want to extract.

I thought of using awk, but it seems awk doesn't have limits on the split across the delimiter.

python has a split() function wherein we can limit the no. of splits, and of the string goes in the last index.
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'right', 'over', 'the little', 'lazy,dog'].

Also, the double quotes should be removed from the final output.

I was trying to use awk, as awk seems faster to me on large file processing. But is it possible to implement such kind of thing, or i need to go with pythonic way of looping and splitting which it seems to be bit slower.

Note: 
1) The no. of columns are fixed.

Please suggest.

Comment: when you get rid of the ',' in "lazy, dog", do you want this to be still the last one column, or two? Also, as an aside, is the number of columns variable or fixed for the file in question?

Comment: Your title `a scenario to be implemented using awk utility` doesn't match your question which allows python solutions.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't get you away from Python, but this seems to be a [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) case, particularly when you mention wanting to remove the quotes around the last item.

test.csv:

```
ay,bee,cee,dee,"ee,eff"
foo,bar,"baz,quux"
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv

fp = open('test.csv', 'r')
for row in csv.reader(fp):
    print row
fp.close()
```

Output:

```
['ay', 'bee', 'cee', 'dee', 'ee,eff']
['foo', 'bar', 'baz,quux']
```

Comment: this will do I/o operations in a loop.. My file is very big which will take too much processor time..

Comment: @user1080454: AWK uses an implicit loop.

Comment: Mite be.. But the I checked with awk the same thing and it gives results on 5crore lines in 2-3 minutes. IF this exceptional case wouldn't have been there. Doesn't awk thing happens such kind of cases.??

Answer (score 2):

Use python's [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module.

```
with open('myfile.txt') as data:
    for line in csv.reader(data):
        print line[2], line[5]
```

It will handle quoting for you seamlessly.

Comment: Yes this can handle, but there is lot many i/o operations which makes the processor go slow. Isnt'd?

Comment: It should be buffered. Did you try this solution and find awk is faster? Or are you just guessing?

Comment: I tried this solution, and I checked that awk gives the output very faster than doing this for each line read (as it involves too many I/O) and seems little slower.. You say.? What your experience say.. as there are around 5crore such lines which i need to read.

Comment: It may be that awk is faster.  I haven't timed it.  It is not, however, doing any more IO than the awk version.  It's reading in the file.  It's printing out the parts you want.  The CSV module has always been fast enough for my needs.  I guess I'm just saying that if you want to use python, don't use split for this kind of task.  It's too inflexible. What if the third column were quoted instead of the last?  It won't work any more. You may find, that once you introduce the necessary complexity to make awkprocess your input properly, it isn't faster anymore.

Comment: hmm.. I am using pythonic way only now in order to process this kind of thing. Thanks for that explanation.!! that works for me..!! I will try it now..

Answer (score 0):

yeah, looks like a csv file there ;)

Here is a `sed` alternative

```
sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"\|\([^,]\+\), \?/\n\1\2/g'
```

this will give you each token in a new line, you can select then which tokens you want

```
$ echo 'the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, right, over, the little, "lazy,foo , bar, fpp,dog"' | sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"\|\([^,]\+\), \?/\n\1\2/g'

the
quick
brown
fox
jumps
right
over
the little
lazy,foo , bar, fpp,dog
```

notice the first line is empty

get the 1st, 4th and last field

```
$ echo 'the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, right, over, the little, "lazy,foo , bar, fpp,dog"' | sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"\|\([^,]\+\), \?/\n\1\2/g' | sed -n '2p;5p;$p'
the
fox
lazy,foo , bar, fpp,dog
```

putting all together (and using *bash*)

```
while read -r; do
    sed 's/"\([^"]\+\)"\|\([^,]\+\), \?/\n\1\2/g' <<< "$REPLY" | sed -n '2p;5p;$p'
done < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Python seems like a better choice to me.

The csv module is great for this, I use it to parse a csv file and insert each line into a database, with that overhead, several hundred thousand lines can be processed quickly, and, as mentioned, it automatically handles the quotes.

If you prefer the split method, then:

```
>>> string = 'the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, right, over, the little, "lazy,dog"'
>>> string = string.replace('"','').split(', ') # note the ', ' not ','
>>> print string
['the', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'right', 'over', 'the little', 'lazy,dog']
```

would preserve your last field intact.

with awk:

```
$ cat tmp
the, quick, brown, fox, jumps, right, over, the little, "lazy,dog"
$ cat tmp | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ", " } ; { print $9 }'
"lazy,dog"
```

Gives you your fields, but doesn't strip the quotes, so you'd have to pipe that to sed or something.  Also note again that the FS is ", " not ","

```
$ cat tmp | awk 'BEGIN { FS = ", " } ; { print $9 }' | sed 's/"//g'
lazy,dog
```

Then, of course, you still have to do whatever it is you want to do with the data, even if one of the cl programs does a specific task faster, I've found that keeping it all in python results in an overall faster process and less headaches.